# Colours weird on PC screen until I play some games (Displayport cable)

Tags: graphics-card, display, colors, displayport

I have recently switched from a HDMI cable to a Displayport one so I can game in 120Hz as my monitor is 120Hz as well. I have had to change my resolution settings in the Nvidia control panel to PC - 1920 x 1080 120Hz as the HD or SD setting did not allow more than 60. So it all works my monitor is working on 120Hz as it should, although the colours are weird (washed/faded out) when I switch my PC on, which I have tried to do something about with changing the colour settings, but that wasn't the best for me. I have realised yesterday after playing 6+ hours of civilization V that the colours were fixed when I have closed the game down and finally, everything looked sharp. I have tried to host a game quickly this morning to see if it will work but it didn't immediately, but while I was writing this I noticed it's getting better gradually. Nvidia GTX 1660 Ti, BenQ 120Hz 24" monitor, i9-9900k CPU.

Comment: Was the display driver downloaded from Nvidia? Is this on Windows?

Comment: Yes it's always been there. Windows 10

Comment: Try this: Start the Nvidia Control Panel, click *Display > Change resolution*, check "Use NVIDIA color settings" and ensure that "Desktop color depth" is set to "Highest (32-bit)" and that "Output dynamic range" is set to "Full". Finally click Apply.

Comment: Tried it, but it's all the same when I start the PC up.

Comment: Might be hardware, some problematic connection maybe needs to warm up.

Comment: That was my original thought, and my friend said as well that it needs to just warm up somehow, but obviously not happy with that when you've spent over £1400 on a rig.

Comment: If you still have warranty, use it.